# how to sort array of objects according to sub property in ng2-order-pipe

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2 project which needs to sort array of objects,
I am using ng2-order-pipe to sort array of objects here an example:

```
<p *ngFor="let customer of customers | orderBy: 'Name'">{{ customer.Name}}</p>
```

The Name attribute is a property in customer, the sort works properly,
but what i want to do is sorting the array according to the customer.Group.Name.
here is the documentation for ng2-order-pipe:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-order-pipe

Comment: Have you tried `orderBy: 'Group.Name'`?

Comment: yes i tried it and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dot operator

```
<p *ngFor="let customer of customers | orderBy: 'Group.Name'">{{ customer.Name}}</p>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t46oeo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: CHECK THE DEMO ABOVE